# Given an array with integer 0 to N, how many ways to arrange it such that array[i] cannot be i

Tags: arrays, algorithm, combinations, permutation

Given an array with integer 0 to N, how many ways to arrange it such that at position i of the array, we cannot have i inserted in it?

For example, N = 2

The following arrangements is valid:

> - 1,2,0
> - 2,0,1

Thus, the answer is 2 arrangements

I can't think of a non-brute force method to do this in O(1) time, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such kind of permutations is called **derangement**. [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) contains a lot of formulas to count them. For example, recurrence:

```
!n=(n-1)(!(n-1)+!(n-2))
```

where `!n`, known as the subfactorial, represents the number of derangements, with the starting values `!0 = 1` and `!1 = 0`