# permuting a list from 1 through 100 such that for any index i, it maps to j not equal to i

Tags: algorithm, permutation

In python, what is an elegant way to permute a list of numbers, such that, for ALL element, indexing is not the same?

For example,
[1,2,3] --> [3,1,2]   OK
[1,2,3] --> [1,3,2]   NOT OK. Because 1 maps to the same 1.

Any good simple code to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want a single permutation or **all** of them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given an array with integer 0 to N, how many ways to arrange it such that array\[i\] cannot be i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51291851/given-an-array-with-integer-0-to-n-how-many-ways-to-arrange-it-such-that-array)

Comment: According to the linked question/answer, these are called derangements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an iterator over all of them.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

def derangements (v):
    n = len(v)
    #print(("entering", v))
    if 0 == n:
        yield []
    elif 1 == n:
        pass # No derangements;
    elif 2 == n:
        # Special case not really needed.
        yield [v[1], v[0]]
    elif 3 == n:
        # Special case not really needed.
        yield [v[1], v[2], v[0]]
        yield [v[2], v[0], v[1]]
    else:
        for i in range(n-1):
            remaining = v[0:i] + v[i+1:n-1]
            # derangements where ith/last are a 2-cycle.
            for w in derangements(remaining):
                before = w[0:i]
                after = w[i:n-1]
                yield before + [v[n-1]] + after + [v[i]]
            # derangements where nth follows ith goes elsewhere
            for w in derangements(v[0:n-1]):
                before = w[0:i]
                after = w[i+1:n-1] if i < n-2 else []
                yield before + [v[n-1]] + after + [w[i]]


for d in derangements(range(5)):
    print(d)
```